# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable (API)

Tags: python

I'm using an API to check for a trading position.

```
size = client.Positions.Positions_myPosition(symbol="BTCUSD").result()[0]['result']['size']
```

When no position, size is "NoneType", so I have this obvious error

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I understand the error but how can I check if size is not null ?

Comment: You must check, which one is `None`? Is it `.result()`? Or `.result()[0]`? Or further down the line? Record up to that point in a variable, then using something like `if resultvar is not None:` process the rest of the chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect `client.Positions.Positions_myPosition(symbol="BTCUSD").result()` returns None. So you could do something like this:

```
position = client.Positions.Positions_myPosition(symbol="BTCUSD").result()
size = 0
if position:
    size = position[0]['result']['size']
else:
    #do something else, throw error, retry...
    pass
```

PS: You can check if something is `None` by doing

```
if myvar is None: ...
if myvar: ... # test if not none
```

But I can only guess what's not working, so please post a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic example for using a `try:`, `catch:` statement:

```
try:
  size = client.Positions.Positions_myPosition(symbol="BTCUSD").result()[0]['result']['size']
except NoneType:
  print('size was of null size!')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the error might be in the fact that you're specifying the arguments in the response when there are no arguments. So, instead of calling the full query as it is, try specifying less arguments.

As an example, instead of doing

```
size = client.Positions.Positions_myPosition(symbol="BTCUSD").result()[0]['result']['size']
```

Try doing,

```
size = client.Positions.Positions_myPosition(symbol="BTCUSD").result()[0]['result']
```

And see if you can spot the size as a null value.